Reaction diffusion equation
I have an issue when I run this code which illustrates the 2D Fisher KPP equation for boundary condition u=0 and initial condition is equal to 1 if (x,y)=(0,0) and0 otherwise , isue finite diffrence method in the code below  :
(* Parameters *)
K = 1; (* Diffusion coefficient *)
r = 1.0; (* Reaction rate *)
L = 20.0; (* Length of domain *)
T = 50.0; (* Total time *)
Nx = 100; (* Number of grid points in x-direction *)
Ny = 100; (* Number of grid points in y-direction *)
Nt = 3000; (* Number of time steps *)
dx = L/(Nx - 1); (* Grid spacing in x-direction *)
dy = L/(Ny - 1); (* Grid spacing in y-direction *)
dt = T/(Nt - 1); (* Time step size *)

(* Create grid *)
x = Table[i*dx, {i, 0, Nx - 1}];
y = Table[j*dy, {j, 0, Ny - 1}];

(* Initial condition *)
initialCondition[x_, y_] := If[x == 0 && y == 0, 1.0, 0.0]
u = Table[initialCondition[x[[i]], y[[j]]], {i, 1, Nx}, {j, 1, 
Ny}];

(* Apply boundary condition *)
applyBoundaryCondition[u_] := (
u[[1, All]] = 0;
u[[Nx, All]] = 0;
u[[All, 1]] = 0;
 u[[All, Ny]] = 0;
  u
  )

 (* Reaction term *)
 reactionTerm[u_] := u * (1 - u)

 (* Finite difference cheme *)
 finiteDifferenceStep[u_] := Module[{uNew, uxx, uyy},
 uNew = u;
 Do[
  uxx = (u[[i + 1, j]] - 2*u[[i, j]] + u[[i - 1, j]])/dx^2;
  uyy = (u[[i, j + 1]] - 2*u[[i, j]] + u[[i, j - 1]])/dy^2;
  uNew[[i, j]] = u[[i, j]] + dt*(K*(uxx + uyy) + reactionTerm[u[[i, 
  j]]]),
  {i, 2, Nx - 1}, {j, 2, Ny - 1}
    ];
  applyBoundaryCondition[uNew]
    ]

   (*Define times to capture solution*)
   captureTimes = {5, 10, 15};
   stepsToCapture = Round[#/dt] & /@ captureTimes;

   (*Initialize list to store solutions*)
   solutions = {};

   (*Iterate over time and save the solutions at specified 
    times*)
   Do[u = finiteDifferenceStep[u];
   If[MemberQ[stepsToCapture, n], AppendTo[solutions, {n*dt, 
   u}]], {n,  1, Nt}]
   (*Ensure solutions are captured*)
   If[Length[solutions] != Length[captureTimes], 
   Print["Error: Not all solutions captured correctly."], 
   Print["Solutions captured at times: ", captureTimes]]

   (*Prepare data for plotting*)
   plotData = 
    Table[{time, 
    Flatten[Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], solution[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 
     Nx}, {j, 1, Ny}], 1]}, {time, solution} /@ solutions];

    (*Plot the results at specified times in 3D*)
     ListPlot3D[#, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "u"}, 
     PlotLabel -> "2D Fisher-KPP Equation Solution at t = " <> 
     ToString[First[#]] <> " s", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
      Mesh -> None, 
      PlotRange -> All] & /@ plotData[[All, 2]]

My problem is that the code doesnt run  so where is the issue please if there is another way to apply finte diffrence scheme to this equation please tell me im sure that i do it mathematically in correct way nut im not sure about the code


What's that theoretical result? Are you trying to reproduce certain result from literature? Please clarify. 2. Definition of BoundaryIndex etc. are missing, not everybody knows your previous question, please keep your question self-contained. 3. initialIndex generated by your code is NotFound, don't you find it strange?


@xzczd thanks for your answer , i modify my question see please my edit ,

You've only responded to the first question in my comment.

@xzczd i modified the code but it doesnt run see please my edit and please do you see another way to apply finite diffrecne scheme to this equation?

It's just another collection of simple mistakes. As I've already suggested under your previous question, you should not use Mathematica like use static programming language like C i.e. writing down dozens of code and executing them all at once. Please code line by line and make sure every line of code is correct. Now, please think about the following as a first step: Execute ListPlot3D[u] or ListPointPlot3D[u] and observe, do you find anything wrong?

@xzczd iexecute but it doesnt show anything thats why i feel that in previous steps i made a mistake

Now, do you see it?: https://i.sstatic.net/27yqaPM6.png

@xzczd  ,there is problem in the axis

Set smaller Nx and Ny e.g. Nx=10; Ny=10; and observe again.

@xzczd i do that and i tried also changing the other parametrs and still have the same issue

Then do you know what's wrong with your definition of u?

@xzczd well u is solution of the Fisherkpp with 0at boundary and with initial data =1if (x,y)=(0,0) and 0 Otherwise ,for the code iwant to use finite difference scheme , is that answer your question?

With the code x = Table[i*dx, {i, 0, Nx - 1}];, what will be the domain of $x$?

@xzczd the domain of
x would be the range of values obtained by multiplying each integer from 0 to Nx-1 by dx?

@xzczd instead of that i should  do : L=10 .;nx = Floor[2*L/dx];
to mention that domain of x\in(-L,L)?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
